# Counting the number of arrangements around a rectangle.

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

In the above picture (a) and (b) are the same rotation and they are different from (c). Now, there are $5\times9!$ such arrangements of $10$ objects around a rectangle. The question is how many of these arrangements have $A$ and $B$ on opposite long sides of the rectangle.

Here is my approach: such an arrangement can be obtained from a square with two objects on each side and adding $A$ and $B$ on opposite sides. For convenience define the operation $"+"$, as follows: for a square $S$ with two objects on each side and a pair $(x,y)$ where $x,y\in \{1,2,3\}$, $S+(x,y)$ gives a rectangle with $3$ objects on the long side and $2$ on the short where $A$ is on the left at position $x$ from top to bottom and in the same way $B$ on the right. Here is a picture to illustrate this:
[image] 
Since there are $9$ such pairs and $8!$ square arrangements I think that the number of ways to arrange the letters in a rectangle so that $A$ and $B$ are on opposite sides is given by $9\times 8!$, but this is not the correct answer, so where did I go wrong ?

Comment: It *is* the correct answer. What do you think is the correct answer, and why?

Comment: In the book I read this in the answer is $3\times 8!$, but there is no solution provided.

Comment: Are you sure you're quoting the question correctly? That's the number of arrangements in which A and B are opposite each other on long sides of the rectangle, not "on opposite long sides of the rectangle".

Comment: The question uses tables instead of rectangles and the exact wording is : "In how many of the arrangements are A and B seated on longer sides of the table across from each other."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in an ambiguity in the book. In the phrase "are A and B seated [at?] longer sides of the table across from each other", "across from each other" may be taken to refer either to the sides or to the people being seated. You took it to refer to the sides, and your calculation is correct for that interpretation of the question. The answer you quote from the book shows that the intended interpretation is that it's the people, not the sides, that are across from each other.